# jQuery - fire document.ready() in a different window/tab after calling window.open

Tags: jquery, ajax, window.open, document-ready

What is the proper way to trigger a document.ready() in the window (myWindow) I'm loading data into given the following code?

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    dataType : 'html',
    data: {
        plogid:parentLogid,
        rnum:childReportNum,
        params:JSON.stringify(params)
    },

    success : function(data){
        func=linkreport&excelout=0&window=1']);
        var myWindow = window.open("","");
        myWindow.document.write(data);

    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

Just to help people understand WHY I'm trying to do this - I need to POST to the url.  I need to POST because the data property params is a JSON string and could be quite large.

My issue is - when the ajax call returns and I write the data to myWindow, I want to then trigger document.ready on myWindow so that the javascript code within will execute.

Comment: Does the $.ajax call actually return HTML?

Comment: Yep - it returns an entire HTML document...not fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `$(document).ready()` will fire after content is put into a newly created window with `document.write()`.  You can see that happen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/RR29U/.

You can't trigger `.ready()` again after it's already been triggered.  It's designed to fire exactly once when the document is originally loaded.

You can create a function that contains the desired code and call that yourself after the dynamic content is loaded.

Also, do you realize that `window.open()` when called from an ajax success handler will not work properly on most browsers because of popup blocking?

Comment: Ok, so that is fine about .ready() - if I make a function (which is easy)  how do I call it from the parent to have it execute on the HTML in the new window?  Lastly - on the popup - not a problem.

Comment: @Ross - Why not have the new window just run it's own code when it's been loaded?  Why do you have to call something from the other window?  You can use [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send a message to the new window and it can then have an event handler to kick off some action based on the message.

Comment: because I can't pass POST to the new window, so I have to open a new window, then put the result of the POST ajax call into the new window, then call a function (presumably from the parent?) from within the parents ajax success to tell the new window "it is time to do so".  The window.postMessage() sounds promising - can you give me a code example?  Thanks so much (I know its a weird use case).

Comment: @Ross - I meant, why doesn't the code that is loaded into the new window just handle its own initialization after the post loads it.  As I showed you, `$(document).ready()` does get called in the newly loaded code in the new window.  In my previous comment, I linked you to the MDN page for `postMessage()` which shows sample code.  You can call public functions in the other window directly, but I'm sure they would execute in the proper context.  The will execute in the proper context if using `postMessage()`.

Comment: that is what it was supposed to do, but for whatever reason the javascript code in the HTML from the first AJAX call isn't being executed when I write the whole HTML into the new window.  In firefox I'd get the NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: in the parent window.  I decided to go a more simple route - push the data to the server in the POST, but then put the data in memcache and return a key reference which I then just use as a get variable...much simpler.  Thanks for the help - I'll mark this as answered because technically it should work.